# Triggering a Rest API call with a JQuery Mobile button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

This is simple but my JS is a bit rusty..
I am trying to trigger a get request by pressing a JQuery Mobile element.
I can see the button but failing to do an actual Get Request

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="generator_button"></p>
</form>
</body>

<script>
$("p").on("tap",function(){
  $.ajax({
    'url' : '192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you try on button click instead on paragraph? like this`$("#generator_button").on("tap",function(){`

Comment: Nope, doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, note: in your markup there is a `Flip switch` of type `checkbox`, not a button, so I believe you may better check the state of the underlying `checkbox` instead of stick to a `tap` event.

Reference: [jQuery Mobile Flip switch](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/flipswitch/)

Moreover, you it would be nice to provide a JQM page structure to the whole stuff.

Here is an example:

```js
function sendRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    'url': '192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on',
    'type': 'GET',
    'success': function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).on("change", "#generator_button", function() {
  var state = $("#generator_button").prop("checked");
  if (state === true) {
    // Flip switch is on
    console.log("Request sent.");
    //sendRequest(); // uncomment
  } else {
    // Flip switch is off
    //...endpoint _off
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="generator_button" id="generator_button">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting... How can I incorporate it with the generator_off endpoint with the same toggle?

Comment: you just only need the else part ... (BTW, your JS is very very rusty! :) glad you find this interesting! Answer updated. Did this helped you?

Comment: Ah yes, found how to do it.. Yea, I haven't touched it almost 2 years now.. It's been a while :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `});` on last line of your javascript.

Your javascript code should look like this

```
$("p").on("tap",function(){
  $.ajax({
    'url' : '192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: based on [jQuery AJAX GET documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) can you try it this way? 

`$.get({
    'url' : '192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on',
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });` It is triggering in my browser, but i do not have that endpoint

Comment: Ok, so I changed to     'url' : 'http://192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on',
and I am getting now: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to change the url to: 'http://192.168.8.110:5000/generator_on and tested it on a browser without an adblock I mentioned to make it work!